# Diferencias entre target _top, _self y _parent

Tags: html

Estaba leyendo sobre HTML en general, y me surgió una duda. Aunque ponga ejemplos, no veo la diferencia entre los target `_top`, `_self` y `_parent`.

Me parecen que hacen exactamente lo mismo, aunque probablemente hagan cosas distintas, no encuentro la diferencia y tampoco sé en qué casos se utilizaría cada uno.

Por ejemplo:

```html
 <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_top">Google _top</a><br>
 
 <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self">Google _self</a> <br>
 
 <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_parent">Google _parent</a> <br>
```

He estado leyendo la explicación de [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp), pero no llego a entenderlo del todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target` es uno de los atributos del elemento `a`, y, como bien indica [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#the-a-element) sirve para indicar el contexto de navegación:

> Default browsing context for hyperlink navigation and §4.10.22 Form
>   submission
>
> ---
>
> Contexto de navegación predeterminado para la navegación de
>   hipervínculos y §4.10.22 Envío de formulario.

Actualmente hay cuatro nombres de Contexto de navegación válidos: `_blank`, `_self`, `_parent`, y `_top`

El el apartado [6.1.5. Browsing context names](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#browsing-context-names), W3C Recommendation explica también en qué consisten y qué efectos tiene cada uno de estos nombres de Contexto según dónde se usen:

> Los contextos de navegación pueden tener un nombre de contexto de
>   navegación. Por defecto, un contexto de navegación no tiene nombre (su
>   nombre no está configurado).
>
> Un nombre de contexto de navegación válido es cualquier cadena con al
>   menos un carácter que no comience con un carácter `U+005F LOW LINE`.
>   (Los nombres que comienzan con un guión bajo están reservados para
>   palabras clave especiales).
>
> Un nombre o palabra clave de contexto de navegación válido es
>   cualquier cadena que sea un nombre de contexto de navegación válido o
>   que sea una coincidencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas ASCII para uno
>   de los siguientes: `_blank`, `_self`, `_parent` o `_top`.
>
> Estos valores tienen diferentes significados en función de si la
>   página está protegida o no, como se resume en la siguiente tabla (no
>   normativa). En esta tabla:
>
> - `current` significa el contexto de navegación en el que se encuentra el enlace o secuencia de comandos,
> - `parent` significa el contexto de navegación principal de aquel en el que se encuentra el enlace o secuencia de comandos,
> - `top` significa el contexto de navegación de nivel superior del enlace o script en el que está,
> - `new` significa que se creará un nuevo contexto de navegación de nivel superior o contexto de navegación auxiliar, sujeto a varias
>     preferencias de usuario y políticas de agente de usuario,
> - `none` significa que no sucederá nada y
> - `maybe new` significa lo mismo que `new` si la palabra clave `allow-popups` también se especifica en el atributo sandbox (o si el
>     usuario anuló el sandboxing), y lo mismo que `none` por lo demás.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
<sub>[Tabla de W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#browsing-context-names) que explica los diferentes contextos de navegación.</sub>

W3C Recommendation define también los contextos de navegación del siguiente modo:

### [`_top`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#top-level-browsing-context)

> A browsing context that is not a nested browsing context has no parent
>   browsing context, and is the top-level browsing context of all the
>   browsing contexts for which it is an ancestor browsing context.
>
> ---
>
> Un contexto de navegación que no es un contexto de navegación anidado
>   ni tiene contexto de navegación principal, y es el contexto de
>   navegación de nivel superior de todos los contextos de navegación para
>   los cuales es un contexto de navegación ancestral.

### [`_parent`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#parent-browsing-context)

> Certain elements (for example, iframe elements) can instantiate
>   further browsing contexts. These are called nested browsing contexts.
>   If a browsing context P has a Document D with an element E that nests
>   another browsing context C inside it, then C is said to be nested
>   through D, and E is said to be the browsing context container of C. If
>   the browsing context container element E is in the Document D, then P
>   is said to be the parent browsing context of C and C is said to be a
>   child browsing context of P. Otherwise, the nested browsing context C
>   has no parent browsing context.
>
> ---
>
> *Aquí `P` hace referencia a `_parent`*
>
> Ciertos elementos (por ejemplo, elementos de iframe) pueden instanciar
>   más contextos de navegación. Estos se llaman contextos de navegación
>   anidados. Si un contexto de exploración `P` tiene un documento D con
>   un elemento E que anida otro contexto de exploración `C` dentro de él,
>   entonces se dice que `C` está anidado a través de `D`, y se dice que
>   `E` es el contenedor del contexto de exploración de `C`. Si el
>   contenedor del contexto de exploración el elemento `E` está en el
>   Documento `D`, luego se dice que `P` es el contexto de exploración
>   principal de `C` y `C` se dice que es un contexto de exploración
>   secundario de `P`. De lo contrario, el contexto de exploración anidado
>   `C` no tiene contexto de exploración principal.

### `_self`

Significa siempre el contexto de navegación actual, como indica la tabla de más arriba.

Creo que queda explicado cada uno. Dar más detalles de los diferentes contextos sería objeto de una pregunta aparte. Ahora puedes hacer pruebas para verificar su funcionamiento según el contexto.